# Python - pywin32 - move the insertion point to the after of first table

Tags: python, pywin32

I have generated my first table with the python pywin32 package. I would like to add another table after the first one. Can anyone help me on that?

## create the first table with 6 rows and 4 columns:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch,constants
mw = Dispatch('Word.Application')
mw.Visible = 1
md = mw.Documents.Add(Template = MYDIR + '\\Template for tests.docx')
rng = md.Range(0,0)
tabletu = md.Tables.Add(rng,6,4)
```

To create the next table what should be the rng? How could I set my Range object? Any tutorial on that?
Also how could I close and save it properly? I used:

```
filename = "CPM Production FAT Procedures.docx"                                   
md.SaveAs(filename)
```

But each time it increases the document number.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`win32com` is just a wrapper for Microsoft's COM API.  All the functions and properties that you are calling are part of the COM API for Word.  You will find that API extensively documented here:

- [Word 2013 developer reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861527(v=office.15).aspx)

You might find the article [Working with Range Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835176(v=office.15).aspx) particularly instructive in this case.

All of the examples will be in VB, but it's fairly trivial to read across to Python/`win32com`.

For your particular problem something like the following should work:

```
rng = md.Range(md.Content.End-1, md.Content.End)
md.Paragraphs.Add(rng)
rng = md.Range(md.Content.End-1, md.Content.End)
another_table = md.Tables.Add(rng,6,4)
```

---

As for your saving issue, I can't reproduce the problem.  If I repeatedly save with the same filename, I see the same file being over-written.